# Unused functions allow undeclared namespace in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We came an interesting case where MSVC doesn't check namespace resolution for unused functions in a templated class. For example:

```
#include <string>

namespace
{
    template<class Iterator>
    struct Foo
    {
        Foo()
        {
        }

        void parse(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
        {
            foo::string a(begin, end - begin);
        }
    };
}

using CharFoo = Foo<const char *>;
CharFoo fooParser;

int main() 
{
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine in MSVC, but gcc and clang both give an error. Is this an MSVC bug technically? Does the C++ standard say anything about this case as to whether or not this is an error?

Comment: Works in both GCC and Clang after changing `foo::string` to `std::string` https://godbolt.org/z/EPvqncWqG but MSVC compiles with `foo::string` don't know if it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In general MSVC does NOT compile any template functions if they are not used at all. Most compilers differ in that point -- they always check the code (where I do not know what the C++ standard says.)